# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at retina.js:12

Tags: jquery, retina.js

I am trying to add retinajs but I am facing this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at retina.js:12

I am trying with js file

```
<script src="/assets/plugins/retinajs/retina.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this library have 2 problems:

1) variable `var exports={};` was lost

https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/issues/269

2) function
`function getImages(images) {
    if (!images) {
        return typeof document !== 'undefined' ? arrayify(document.querySelectorAll(selector)) : [];
    } else {
        return typeof images.forEach === 'function' ? images : arrayify(images);
    }
}`

on input recive incorrect argument

https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/issues/273

Add variable, 
replace function code by line

`return typeof document !== 'undefined' ? arrayify(document.querySelectorAll(selector)) : [];`

Have fun!